# LINQ to XML Selecting Child Elements

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am trying to extract information from an XML file into an object using LINQ to XML. Although I can return the document and section Id attributes I cannot get access to the Items for each section element, it returns an IEnumerable of all the items in the document. I know this is correct as I’m calling Descendants but am struggling to get it to return only the child items of each section element. Can anybody help?

**XML Document**

```xml
<root>
<document id="1">
  <section id="1.1">
    <item id="1.1.1"></item>
    <item id="1.1.2"></item>
    <item id="1.1.3"></item>
  </section>
  <section id="1.2">
    <item id="1.2.1"></item>
    <item id="1.2.2"></item>
  </section>
</document>
</root>
```

**LINQ Query**

```
XElement documentRoot = XElement.Load("document.xml");
var documents = (from docs in documentRoot.Descendants("document")
                 select new
                    {
                        Id = (string) docs.Attribute("id"),
                        Sections = docs.Elements("section"),
                        Items = docs.Elements("section").Elements("item")
                    }).ToList();

foreach(var doc in documents)
{
    foreach(var section in doc.Sections)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SectionId: " + section.Attribute("Id"));  
        foreach(var item in doc.Items)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ItemId: " + section.Attribute("Id"));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little unclear as to the objective.  Your anonymous object is composed of the document ID, all the sections in the document, and all the items in all the sections of the document.   If you're trying to reconstruct the XML hierarchy as an anonymous object, you're going to need multiple queries.  Why not just use the XML in that case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got some small typos, on attribute `Id` and at item loop. But if you're trying to get all section items into that items collection, you're wrong at design level, as `Items` should be a `Section` property, not `Document` (so you'll need to query your XML twice).

Or, you can to do something like:

```
var documents =
    (from docs in documentRoot.Descendants("document")
     select new
     {
         Id = (string) docs.Attribute("id"),
         Sections = docs.Elements("section")
     }).ToList();

foreach (var doc in documents)
{
    foreach (var section in doc.Sections)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SectionId: " + section.Attribute("id"));
        foreach (var item in section.Elements("item"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ItemId: " + item.Attribute("id"));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
SectionId: id="1.1"
ItemId: id="1.1.1"
ItemId: id="1.1.2"
ItemId: id="1.1.3"
SectionId: id="1.2"
ItemId: id="1.2.1"
ItemId: id="1.2.2"
```

Comment: Sorry about typos but still doesnt solve the problem. What I am trying to acheive is that only the items that are children to the each section are returned.

Comment: @Cragly, I just rewrote my answer, take a look

Comment: Excellent! works like a charm. Such a simple fix. Must not have been able to see the wood for the trees as spent so long looking at this one. Good man.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want a flat structure ?!?! (from LinqPad)

```
XElement documentRoot  = XElement.Parse (
@"<root> 
<document id='1'> 
  <section id='1.1'> 
    <item id='1.1.1'></item> 
    <item id='1.1.2'></item> 
    <item id='1.1.3'></item> 
  </section> 
  <section id='1.2'> 
    <item id='1.2.1'></item> 
    <item id='1.2.2'></item> 
  </section> 
</document> 
</root> 
");




var documents = (from docs in documentRoot.Descendants("section") 
                 select new 
                    { 
                        SectionId = (string) docs.Attribute("id"), 
                        Items = docs.Elements("item") 
                    }); 
 documents.Dump();
```

This gives 2 `SectionId` items that containes `XElement`s with related items.

Comment: Thanks for the post but what I would idealy like is to be able to access those contained item XElements and assign them to the Items property of the object so I get an IEnumerable<XElement> of items associated with its specific section.

Comment: Can you give an example of the datastructure you would like to have. Why XElement instead of a type?!?!