# LINQ query to XML file to get child tags

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am loading a XML into XMLDocument.

Below is its structure:

```
<REPORT id="Loan" version="20120710160558">
    <FILE id="Loan_20120710">
        <INDEX NAME="Amount" VALUE="45000" PAGE="1"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Amount" VALUE="20000" PAGE="2"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Amount" VALUE="32494" PAGE="3"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Name" VALUE="Christie" PAGE="1"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Name" VALUE="Christie" PAGE="2"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Name" VALUE="Christie" PAGE="3"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Date" VALUE="02082012" PAGE="1"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Date" VALUE="02082012" PAGE="2"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Date" VALUE="02082012" PAGE="3"/>
    </FILE>
    <FILE id="Loan_20120712">
        <INDEX NAME="Amount" VALUE="34984" PAGE="1"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Amount" VALUE="34984" PAGE="2"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Amount" VALUE="34984" PAGE="3"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Name" VALUE="Charles" PAGE="1"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Name" VALUE="Charles" PAGE="2"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Name" VALUE="Charles" PAGE="3"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Date" VALUE="03082012" PAGE="1"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Date" VALUE="03082012" PAGE="2"/>
        <INDEX NAME="Date" VALUE="03082012" PAGE="3"/>
    </FILE>
</REPORT>
```

I am trying with below LINQ query:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(XMLFile);

var query = from xml in xdoc.Descendants("File")
                               select new 
                               {
                                   Amount = (string)xml.Element("Amount"),
                                   Name = (string)xml.Element("Name"),
                                   Date = (string)xml.Element("Date")

                               };
```

I am facing errors with above query.

I want to use the LINQ query to get the values of Amount,Name and contract so that I will update in database?

Comment: Maybe you can try this? (Not sure though)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2089799/linq-to-xml-selecting-child-elements

Comment: You're trying to get an element with names `Amount`, `Name` and `Date`, though there are only __attributes__ with name `NAME`, `VALUE` and `PAGE`. I think you want to read the attributes first and try to pivot it later.

Comment: can you use XDocument instead of XmlDocument?

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance when accessing amount vaule.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var doc= XDocument.Load(filePath);

var query = from file in doc.Element("REPORT").Elements("FILE")
            from index in file.Elements("INDEX")
            select new 
            {
                File = file.Attribute("id").Value,
                Name = index.Attribute("NAME").Value,
                Value = index.Attribute("VALUE").Value,
                Page = Int32.Parse(index.Attribute("PAGE").Value)
            };
```

Then if you wish to pivot the list:

```
var pivotQuery = query.GroupBy(p => new {p.File, p.Page}).Select(g => new
{
    File = g.Key.File,
    Page = g.Key.Page,
    Amount = g.Where(p => p.Name == "Amount").First().Value,
    Name = g.Where(p => p.Name == "Name").First().Value,
    Date = g.Where(p => p.Name == "Date").First().Value
});
```

You can combine these queries into a single one if you want as well.